# vlookup using an =IF formula cell as the reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to use a vlookup where the reference cell is an IF formula:

Formula: =VLOOKUP(D14,'Incomplete Report'!A13:C22,3,FALSE)
Reference Cell Formula: =IF(A14=$B$11:$B$1079,0,A14)

The formula returns a #N/A error.

I think I'm somehow supposed to tell excel to read the cell as a value instead of a formula, but I don't know the correct formula.

Your guidance is appreciated!

Comment: VLOOKUP will look for the value returned by the formula in cell D14, you don't have to tell it that. Your problem must be something else. Please provide information about what is in cell D14 as well as `'Incomplete Report'!A13:C22`.

Comment: What do you mean by Reference Cell Formula?  Is that D14, the range you are looking in, or the cell you want the data from?

Comment: Please post some sample data and what you expect to find. I expect your problem is in your IF statement, you say "IF A14 is a range..." as far as I am aware an if statement in excel needs to compare specific values not ranges.

Comment: Upload the sample data, since Data Range in If  Formula and VLookup has no co-ordination, both are out  of Data range!!

Answer (score 0):

The formula in the Reference Cell looks incorrect.

You ask whether the value in the cell `A14` is equal to the value in the array `B11:B1079`.  Since a single cell cannot be equal to a number of cells, the result will always be 0 (according to the formula).

The vlookup then searches the first column in the range (given in the vlookup function) in `Incomplete Report` for the 0 figure and doesn't find it, resulting in the #N/A error.  This can be tested by changing one of the values in A13:A22 in the `Incomplete Report` sheet to 0.

You need to correct the formula in D14 to something that will return a useful value to lookup.  I can't tell what you want the formula in that cell to do, so cannot say what the answer is.  It might help if you supply some data that exists in B11:B1079 and the A13:C22 array in `Incomplete Report'.

Comment: #Mcalex,, a Cell value can be searched in the Data Range and the If Formula has no error.

Comment: Thank you all for your guidance.  @mcalex, ultimately I have 3 sheets.

Sheet 1 has data set #1
A1: 1
B1: 2
C1: 4
C1: 5

Sheet 2 has data set #2
A1: 1
B2: 2
C1: 3

Sheet 3 is where I want the data returned.
If the value in 'Sheet1'!A1 is found in 'Sheet2'!A1:C1 I want it to return the value in the array in 'Sheet2'!A1:C1 that is not found.
I couldn't get the formula to work across sheets, so I moved the values in Sheet 1 & 2 to Sheet 3 and referenced is in the array B11:B1079.
Really messy and wrong, I know. Sorry...